# Why the compose and identity method is omitted in Bifunction interface Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I have just started reading Java 8 concepts while reading I found something which was not convincing me enough that is the omission of `compose` and `identity` method in `BiFunction` Interface. As far as I could read from Java 8 documentation I could see `Bifunction` seems to be in same as `Function` interface expect that it takes an additional arguments so in such case `Bifunction` should have all features as that of `Function` interface, but it is not so.

Hence, can anyone help me find reason behind omitting these methods?

Comment: Documentation: "*`identity()` - Returns a function that always returns its input argument*" how should that work with 2 inputs? Almost same for `compose`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Function.identity()` returns a `Function` that accepts a single argument and returns that argument.

A `BiFunction` has two arguments, so which one of them would `identity()` return?

Similarly, `compose()` is used to compose two `Function`s by passing the result of the first `Function` as the single argument expected by the second `Function`.

How would you implement something similar for a function that takes two arguments? The first function will result in a single value, but the second function required two arguments.

You can still compose a `BiFunction` with a `Function` by passing the result of the `BiFunction` as an argument for the `Function`. For that purpose you have [**andThen**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-).

For example, suppose you have a `BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer>` as follows:

```
BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer> mul = (x,y) -> x*y;
```

and you have a `Function<Integer,Integer>`:

```
Function<Integer,Integer> plus5 = x -> x + 5;
```

You can compose them with `andThen` as follows:

```
BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer> mulPlus5 = mul.andThen(plus5);
```

and call it:

```
int result = mulPlus5.apply(2,3); // this will multiply 2*3 and add 5, resulting in 11.
```

You cannot apply `plus5` (or some `BiFunction` as an alternative) first and then pass its result to `mul`, since `mul` takes 2 arguments, while applying `plus5` (or any other `Function` or `BiFunction`) will result in a single value.

Comment: Thanks Eran, I think that is appropriate observation with identity method can you kindly help me even in identifying case for Compose method

Comment: Hi Eran,So in that case even andThen method also should have been omitted right can you kindly give an example and elaborate it more for compose method

Comment: @srikzen `andThen` wasn't omitted, since it accepts a `Function` at its parameter, and you can apply that `Function` on the result of the `BiFunction`. `compose` works the other way around - you pass to it the Function to be applied first, and the result of the Function is fed to the Function on which it was called. You can't do that with a BiFunction, since a BiFunction required two arguments.

Comment: I disagree with the premise about *identity*. Would it have been so hard for the Java engineers to implement Bifunction.returnFirst() and Bifunction.retunSecond() or whatever names would best suit them?